# event.dispatchEvent is not a function (no jQuery!)

Tags: javascript, dispatchevent

In a main.js-File I have the following function

```
function fireCustomEvent(element, event) {
if (document.createEventObject) {
    // dispatch for IE
    var evt = document.createEventObject();
    return element.fireEvent('on' + event, evt);
}
else {
    // dispatch for firefox + others
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent(event, true, true); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
    console.log("dispatch");
    return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

}

On one page, this code works just fine, but at another page, I get the "event.dispatchEvent is not a function" - Error.
I've read that "jQuery.noConflict()" would do the Job but since i have no jQuery (or any js-Framework) in my project I wonder, how that can be. I've tried it anyway, but then I only get (logically) the "jQuery is not defined" - Error.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: what is element here?  if it works in one page but not another, it's possible that the 2nd page is passing an invalid parameter

Comment: `dispatchEvent` has nothing to do with jQuery, so `jQuery.noConflict()` is irrelevant.

Comment: Robert: ouch, you're right, I should take a break... but thank you!!!

Comment: @NiklasHantke if you want him to see your comment, you need to use `@handle`. Type `@r` and then use TAB for name completion.

Comment: @Barmar: Thank you for the tip but unfortunately the edit-time has expired :(

Comment: @Barmar it's because all the SO questions regarding 'element.dispatchEvent is not a function' have answers stating that it's a result of a conflict between jQuery and some other JS framework like Prototype. I've been searching for ages and can't find any solution except 'jQuery.noConflict()' (which as you've rightly pointed out is completely irrelevant).